# node cluster share data between master and clusters

Tags: javascript, node.js, cluster-computing

I started to using node cluster package and i quickly found that data is not being shared between master and clusters. Lets take this example:

```
var cluster = require('cluster');
var numCPUs = require('os').cpus().length;

var my_array = [];

if(cluster.isMaster) {
    for (var i = 0; i < numCPUs && i < 8; i++) {
        cluster.fork();
    }

    my_array.push('test');

    cluster.on('exit', function(worker, code, signal) {
        console.log('worker ' + worker.process.pid + ' died');
    });
} else {
    setInterval(function() {
        console.log(my_array); // my_array is always empty
    }, 500);
}
```

how do i define variables that can be shared between master and clusters?

Comment: With [message](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html#cluster_event_message) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cluster just open more process (child process) that way they listing to the same port . in order to communicant you need so send massages between them. here is an example 
[node-cluster-messaging.js](https://gist.github.com/bamoo456/7f0a99400ed088da87170dac3e386000)